# Negating Parts in Blender and Exporting Incorrectly

Tags: modeling, rendering

Recently, I've decided to get into 3D modeling. I decided Blender is the easiest to use (by opinion) but I've ran into an issue :(

I was using the plugin Bool Tool, but when I exported it, it looked like this:[image]
It shows this in the Windows 10' default 3D viewer and some random online 3D viewer so I doubt it's 'renderer-specific'

I wasn't expecting this because in Blender it shows this:[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to enable something, or is this just not possible?
I was expecting the Bool Tool to persist in exports.. Is there something in settings or so?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to Blender 
I'm using Blender 2.93.0

Note: I created the model on a different computer which I currently don't have access to so I'm not sure which version of Blender I used... Sorry

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing `tab` to get into edit mode, `a` to select all faces, and `Ctrl+T` to triangulate faces before exporting. Looks like either the file format or the viewers are struggling with the number of faces.

Keep in mind this is destructive so you can't go back... might be wise to do in an exporting copy of the `.blend` file.

If this doesn't work try recreating the geometry using the `boolean modifier` and applying the modifier before (or while) exporting. (Suggesting because you're new and you'll save headaches learning the core Blender functionality first, then addons designed for rare use cases. Boolean modifier would handle this with ease.)

[image]

Comment: Alright. I'll try this, but I didn't really understand the last part of your answer (about recreating the boolean modifier). If this is helpful, the model has: 1,498 tris, 675 faces and 796 verts

Comment: yeah, original explanation was confusing. clarified the wording and added a screenshot, hope that helps!

Comment: Nice, it worked. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Np! Can you click the star or the up arrow to accept the answer? Blender is the best!

Comment: Yup, I already did!